# Display Name of the State along with Latitude and Longitude in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation

Initially I displayed the current latitude and longitude in the application using the following code:

```
package com.coders.location;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    private double wayLatitude = 0.0, wayLongitude = 0.0;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;
    private android.widget.Button btnLocation;
    private TextView txtLocation;
    private android.widget.Button btnContinueLocation;
    private TextView txtContinueLocation;
    private StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    private boolean isContinue = false;
    private boolean isGPS = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.txtContinueLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtContinueLocation);
        this.btnContinueLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContinueLocation);
        this.txtLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLocation);
        this.btnLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(10 * 1000); // 10 seconds
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000); // 5 seconds

        new GpsUtils(this).turnGPSOn(new GpsUtils.onGpsListener() {
            @Override
            public void gpsStatus(boolean isGPSEnable) {
                // turn on GPS
                isGPS = isGPSEnable;
            }
        });

        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                *******************************************************
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        wayLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                        wayLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                        if (!isContinue) {
                            txtLocation.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%s - %s", wayLatitude, wayLongitude));
                        } else {
                            stringBuilder.append(wayLatitude);
                            stringBuilder.append("-");
                            stringBuilder.append(wayLongitude);
                            stringBuilder.append("\n\n");
                            txtContinueLocation.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                        }
                *******************************************************

                        if (!isContinue && mFusedLocationClient != null) {
                            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        btnLocation.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            if (!isGPS) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn on GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            isContinue = false;
            getLocation();
        });

        btnContinueLocation.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (!isGPS) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn on GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            isContinue = true;
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            getLocation();
        });
    }

    private void getLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    AppConstants.LOCATION_REQUEST);

        } else {
            if (isContinue) {
                mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
            } else {
                mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, location -> {
                    if (location != null) {
                        wayLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                        wayLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                        txtLocation.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%s - %s", wayLatitude, wayLongitude));
                    } else {
                        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1000: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (isContinue) {
                        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
                    } else {
                        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, location -> {
                            if (location != null) {
                                wayLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                                wayLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                                txtLocation.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%s - %s", wayLatitude, wayLongitude));
                            } else {
                                mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == AppConstants.GPS_REQUEST) {
                isGPS = true; // flag maintain before get location
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I did this the code was working well. Then I tried to update the code as I needed to display the State of the current location as well "i.e. Display the state in where the users Phone is currently located(e.g. South Carolina, Massachusetts, California, etc.).

This was the updated code:

```
package com.coders.location;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

    private double wayLatitude = 0.0, wayLongitude = 0.0;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;
    private android.widget.Button btnLocation;
    private TextView txtLocation;
    private android.widget.Button btnContinueLocation;
    private TextView txtContinueLocation;
    private StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    private boolean isContinue = false;
    private boolean isGPS = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.txtContinueLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtContinueLocation);
        this.btnContinueLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContinueLocation);
        this.txtLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLocation);
        this.btnLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(10 * 1000); // 10 seconds
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000); // 5 seconds

        new GpsUtils(this).turnGPSOn(new GpsUtils.onGpsListener() {
            @Override
            public void gpsStatus(boolean isGPSEnable) {
                // turn on GPS
                isGPS = isGPSEnable;
            }
        });

        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                *******************************************************
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        wayLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                        wayLongitude = location.getLongitude();

                        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                        try {
                            List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

                            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                                    stringBuilder.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                                stringBuilder.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                                stringBuilder.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                                stringBuilder.append(address.getCountryName());
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e){

                        }


                        if (!isContinue) {
                            txtLocation.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                        } else {
                            stringBuilder.append(wayLatitude);
                            stringBuilder.append("-");
                            stringBuilder.append(wayLongitude);
                            stringBuilder.append("\n\n");
                            txtContinueLocation.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                        }
                *******************************************************
                        if (!isContinue && mFusedLocationClient != null) {
                            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        btnLocation.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            if (!isGPS) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn on GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            isContinue = false;
            getLocation();
        });

        btnContinueLocation.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (!isGPS) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please turn on GPS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            isContinue = true;
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            getLocation();
        });
    }

    private void getLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    AppConstants.LOCATION_REQUEST);

        } else {
            if (isContinue) {
                mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
            } else {
                mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, location -> {
                    if (location != null) {
                        wayLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                        wayLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                        txtLocation.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%s - %s", wayLatitude, wayLongitude));
                    } else {
                        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1000: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (isContinue) {
                        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
                    } else {
                        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, location -> {
                            if (location != null) {
                                wayLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                                wayLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                                txtLocation.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%s - %s", wayLatitude, wayLongitude));
                            } else {
                                mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == AppConstants.GPS_REQUEST) {
                isGPS = true; // flag maintain before get location
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code now doesn't even display the current latitude and longitude. Can someone help me with this. I'm looking to display the State as well as the Lat and Long of the current location.

The lines of Code where the changes have been implemented and that seems the most relevant to my issue are marked with a long line of asterisk at the Start and End of the code which looks like this:
                *******************************************************

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All we need to do is add this permission in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

And create a LocationManager instance like this:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Check if GPS is enabled or not.
```

And then implement LocationListener and get coordinates:

```
LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
Here is the sample code to do so
```

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        editLocation.setText("");
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(
                getBaseContext(),
                "Location changed: Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Lng: "
                    + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
        Log.v(TAG, longitude);
        String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
        Log.v(TAG, latitude);

        /*------- To get city name from coordinates -------- */
        String cityName = null;
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                    loc.getLongitude(), 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String s = longitude + "\n" + latitude + "\n\nMy Current City is: "
            + cityName;
        editLocation.setText(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

see this flow:
[How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Actually this code will not work now.
Google has deprecated the above code and now you need to use below code.

I used Retrofit 
Retrofit Client

```
public static final String GOOGLE_ETA = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/";

public static Retrofit getEtaClient() {
    if (retrofitEtaGoogle == null) {
        retrofitEtaGoogle = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(GOOGLE_ETA)
                .client(provideOkHttpClient())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofitEtaGoogle;
}
```

Api interface class

```
@GET("api/geocode/json?key="+ Consts.GOOGLE_API_KEY)
Call<GoogleGeoCodeApiResponseModel> getPlaceFromLatLng(@Query("latlng") String latLng);
```

In updateLocationUI() method

```
String latLng = location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude();
    ApiInterface apiInterface = RetrofitClient.getEtaClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<GoogleGeoCodeApiResponseModel> call = apiInterface.getPlaceFromLatLng(latLng);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<GoogleGeoCodeApiResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<GoogleGeoCodeApiResponseModel> call, Response<GoogleGeoCodeApiResponseModel> response) {

            if (response.body().getStatus() != null && response.body().getStatus().equals("OK")) {
                addressObj = new GoogleAddressLocalModel();
                addressObj.setName(response.body().getResults().get(0).getFormattedAddress());
                addressObj.setLat(response.body().getResults().get(0).getGeometry().getLocation().getLat());
                addressObj.setLng(response.body().getResults().get(0).getGeometry().getLocation().getLng());
                for (GoogleGeoCodeApiResponseModel.AddressComponent obj : response.body().getResults().get(0).getAddressComponents()) {
                    for (String type : obj.getTypes()) {
                        if (type.contains("postal_code")) {
                            addressObj.setPostalCode(obj.getLongName());
                        } else if (type.contains("country")) {
                            addressObj.setCountryId(obj.getShortName());
                            addressObj.setCountryName(obj.getLongName());
                        } else if (type.contains("administrative_area_level_2")) {
                            addressObj.setCityName(obj.getLongName());
                        }
                    }
                }


            } else if (response.body().getStatus() != null) {
                Log.e("ErrroGettingAddress", response.body().getStatus());

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<GoogleGeoCodeApiResponseModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("ErrroGettingAddress", t.getLocalizedMessage());

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you shed some light on how to use retrofit client and where to add the API interface class in the code

Comment: sure, you can follow this link. 
https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23
you will get everything you want to know about retrofit.

Comment: My code only started working. Thanks for the help tough!

Comment: does my answer helped you?